# Twitter API - get Account Details from consumerKey and consumerToken

Tags: api, twitter

I inherited an application that has tons of users already authorized to get twitter data on their behalf.

The problem is the guy who created is not around anymore and I am left with consumerKey and consumerToken only.

That in itself is sufficient to interact with twitter API, but I now need to know the account details ( in particular the screen_name that created the app) .

I could not find any API to get such details.  Any ideas on how to get it.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a direct way to find the app owner's screen name, but here are a few things you can do to investigate:

1. Use the ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret, that you have, to start the OAuth process.
2. On the Twitter Authorization screen, you can see the name of the app and who created it.
3. You might be able to do a Twitter search for the person who created the app and get their screen name.
4. Continue to authorize the app - this will put it in your app list.
5. Visit your personal Twitter Settings tab, click on Apps, and find the App that you authorized.
6. Click on the owner's name, which will lead you to a Web site.
7. The Web site might be the company Web site, in which case, there is no further help.
8. The Web site might belong to the owner and it might have a link to the owner's Twitter account where you can get their screen name.

Just know that there's nothing keeping you from using the ConsumerKey/ConsumerSecret that the other guy set up. You can create your own app - preferably with an account that belongs to the company with credentials that the company can access if you're no longer around. Then use the ConsumerKey/ConsumerSecret from the new app on subsequent deployments.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I guessed.  I was applying for the site stream and twitter wanted to know who the appname.  I wanted to ensure I give the right information provided how tough its already to get an app whitelisted on a site stream.